# Cannot assign to ' ' because it is a 'method group'

Tags: c#, calculator, method-group

I am new to C# and programming in general, for my assignment at university I have been asked to program a calculator and I am running into some trouble, here is my code:

```
    private bool IsInfinity(long result)
    {
        if (result > Int32.MaxValue || result < Int32.MinValue)
        {
            errorFound = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private double Add(double number1, double number2)
    {
        if (IsInfinity = true)
        {
            errorFound = true;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            double result = number1 + number2;
            result = Math.Round(result, 2);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble with the line,

```
    if (IsInfinity = true)
```

as it is causing an error that reads, "Cannot assign to 'IsInfinity' because it is a 'method group'", I am struggling to find a solution to this and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: IsInfinity is a method taking an argument. It should be if(IsInfinity(long number))

Comment: What do you think that line means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues.

First, `IsInfinity` is a method (or group of methods, if there are multiple overloads), so you need to invoke it with some parameters.  Something like

```cs
IsInfinity(number1)
```

Second, you are trying to *set* the method to true, rather than *comparing* its result to true.  What you want is

```cs
if(IsInfinity(number1) == true)
```

(notice the two equal signs).  Or, more tersely,

```cs
if(IsInfinity(number1))
```

(since it already returns true, and you don't need to do the comparison again.)

Comment: I would recommend formatting your answer to put your (pseudo) code in a block for readability.